# Core data: How will you avoid duplicate while inserting data in coredata

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, afincrementalstore

I am using core data and have an `NSManagedObjectContext` subclass for my model.

On `viewDidLoad`:

1. I am trying to fetch from core data.
2. Also starting a network call, which on success will save the model objects to core data and fetch again to update the UI.

The problem I faced is on each `viewDidLoad` I had the data added again and again meaning if I have 4 results from the n/w call, I will have 2 sets of the same 4 results if I have loaded the view for the second time and so on.

I avoided this by checking for duplication manually before saving the network fetched results.

I don't think this is a clean approach and also I want to use `NSFetchedResultsController` for `UICollectionView` to make the fetch more efficient.

Would using `NSFetchedResultsController` help in anyway avoiding the problem?

Also has anyone tried **AFIncrementalStore** or **SSDataKit** wrappers for core data? Any suggestions on which one would be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use it, [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit) will do it for you. But it basically does the same thing. It offers some caching options to make the duplication check quick but there still has to be a check somewhere.

I'm not sure how you think the FRC could help with the duplication check. Using a fetch request to get a dictionary result containing only the appropriate identification attributes maybe, but not a full FRC.

Core Data itself has no concept of a 'duplicate'. See the Apple documentation section 'Implementing Find-or-Create Efficiently' [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003174-SW1) for recommendations.

Comment: So do you mean these duplicate avoiding are available only via core data wrappers, not directly in to the coredata.
Also I looked at couple of options SSDataKit and AFIncrementalStore, do you have any idea which one is best.